# SOLR Exception in thread "Scanner-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: solr

`SOLR Gets Hang` , When I check the `stderrout.log`  of `Jetty` this was the error:

```
Exception in thread "Scanner-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found It ,

Increase heap size of Java:

You could use java -Xmx4096m in order to set your heap to 4 GB.

you could then add export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx4096m to your shell by their (.bashrc, .zshrc) file.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/542585/how-to-increase-java-heap-size